# Require asp:TextBox when specific asp:CheckBoxList ListItem checked

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I'm not finding any examples of requiring a textbox be filled out when a specific checkbox in a `CheckBoxList` is checked.  I find plenty of examples of stand alone CheckBoxes. I understand the `CheckBoxList` is a unique animal and does not have a built-in required validator.

I need the user to complete a related textbox when they check the "Other" box in a list of check boxes. It would be nice to show/hide the textbox based upon that box being checked as well.

Comment: it should be from front-end side or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all else fails, create a `CustomValidator`. With that you can write your own rules for when an element or multiple elements are valid or not. However for this to work I added the `checkBoxListValidator` class to the CheckBoxList to be able to find it with jQuery.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" CssClass="checkBoxListValidator">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option A" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option B" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option C" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Style="display: none"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" Text="Please fill out the TextBox" ClientValidationFunction="requiredFieldIfOther"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function requiredFieldIfOther(sender, element) {
        var isValid = true;
        var textBoxToValidate = $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>");
        $('.checkBoxListValidator input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "-1" && $(this).prop("checked") == true && textBoxToValidate.val() == "") {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });
        element.IsValid = isValid;
    }
```

As a bonus the code to show and hide the textbox based on the `other` checkbox.

```
    $('.checkBoxListValidator input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var textBoxToValidate = $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>");
        if ($(this).val() == "-1" && $(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            textBoxToValidate.prop("style", "display:block");
        } else {
            textBoxToValidate.prop("style", "display:none");
        }
    });
</script>
```